# How will a damaged logbook affect pursuing a career as a professional pilot?

Tags: commercial-aviation, logging

I recently damaged my log book by putting it in the washer machine. I have picked through all the pieces and saved what little legible logs are left. I have requested a copy of my 8710 from the FAA. With sudden funding I have decided to pursue a career as a professional pilot. I have contacted the owner of the previous aircraft flown and requested copies of the aircraft logs. With all the information, I plan on reconstructing my log book. My question is, with my 8710 proving that I did receive my license, I also had an additional 40-50 hours of flight time that I would like to put in my log book. Should I expect any future hiccups with additional ratings and employment as a pilot? What else could I do to make this process smoother?

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/767/how-does-a-pilot-replace-their-logbook-if-it-has-been-lost

Answer (score 10):

Well, you've already covered the ["What to do if you've lost your logbook"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/767/how-does-a-pilot-replace-their-logbook-if-it-has-been-lost) bit.  The remaining bit of your question is a little trickier to answer, but not as bad as you might think.

The good part about renting is that as you've noted you can get the rental records & that gives you a good start on at least the hours portion of reconstructing your logs. The Day/Night, Instrument/Simulated Instrument, and destinations (Cross-Country) times may be a bit harder to reconstruct, but with a little luck you'll be able to piece that together too.

- **Will you have trouble with additional ratings?** No.
  This is the tricky bit though: You *will* need logs that prove that you meet the aeronautical experience requirements for any new rating you're pursuing, so if you're working through your instrument/commercial/multi and you just washed the records of that training time, cross-country time, etc. you're going to need to either reconstruct that (from rental records & landing fee receipts), fly the hours over again, or some combination of the two.
  The same goes for any endorsements you have (tailwheel, high-performance, etc.) - you'll need to get re-endorsed to have a record of those (and if you show up to your next practical test in an aircraft that requires an endorsement the examiner may ask to see that endorsement).
- **Will you have trouble with employment?** I doubt it.
  Your certificates are your major qualification, and you'll have those (subject to reconstructing the requisite aeronautical experience entries like I mentioned above).
  You'll want to reconstruct as much of your logs as possible because all that experience *should* count when you go sit down with an employer, but if you've "only" washed ~50 hours you'll make up most or all of that experience in your future training.

---

A few related questions you might want to look at:

- [What is the best way to keep logbook entries backed up?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-logbook-entries-backed-up/)
  (For my part: I scan each page once I've filled it.)
- [Are there any best practices for transitioning from paper logbooks to electronic logbooks?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11327/are-there-any-best-practices-for-transitioning-from-paper-logbooks-to-electronic)
  (if you decide to go that route)